# Sphinx with rst2odt.py

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I really like a lot of the features of Sphinx, but I also require the final output to be docx. I've had great luck with .rst -> .odt -> .docx using rst2odt.py (`docutils`) and LibreOffice. I noticed that Sphinx can generate "Docutils XML". In my mind, I should be able to use that and then go to .odt through the same mechanism as rst2odt.py does. However, I'm not sure how I would go about that. I realize that there is a package `sphinxcontrib-docxbuilder`, but it uses `python-docx` internally which has rather limited table support based on my experiments. I am using rst specifically because of the ability to do column/row spanning in a very clean way.

The alternative that I'm currently considering is to use something like `jinja2` to do all the stuff I would need Sphinx for and stick stick with rst2odt.py.

Comment: Can you provide an example of a table that does not work in the pipeline you suggested?